# How to get the active tab in Trigger.io

Tags: tabs, trigger.io

I'm working on [OpenForge](https://github.com/trigger-corp/browser-extensions) browser addon. Is it possible to get the current/active tab object?

Answer (score 0):

The tabbar component doesn't have a `button.getActive(success, error)` function, so the only way to determine this is to store the active tab in a JavaScript variable when a tab button is tapped.

Example:

```
forge.tabbar.addButton({
  icon: "search.png",
  text: "Search",
  index: 0
}, function (button) {
  // action to perform when button is clicked
  button.onPressed.addListener(function () {
    alert("Search");
    // store active button to variable
    active_tab = 'search';
  });
});
```